# Two identical methods "vertex_disjoint_paths" and "cohesion" in the library?

Tags: python, igraph

I am concerted about the existence of two identical methods of the same functionality in the igraph library for python.
The functions are: "vertex_disjoint_paths" and "cohesion" for the $k-vertex-connectivity$.
And, similarly, "edge_disjoint_paths" and "adhesion" for $k-edge-connectivity$.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is here. :) Yes, they are identical. The reason is visibility. We want people to be able to find these methods by either names.

Comment: you call it "visibility", I call it "redundancy" :)
thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just aliases:

```
>>> from igraph import Graph
>>> Graph.adhesion == Graph.edge_connectivity == Graph.edge_disjoint_paths
True
>>> Graph.cohesion == Graph.vertex_connectivity == Graph.vertex_disjoint_paths
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I should modify the question title to" three identical...."